# Should have more stats on stackoverflow visible to all the users?

Tags: feature-request, statistics

I feel sometimes for fun we can have more statistics about the users say on stackoverflow...for example like how many users from every country?...who got the most reputation points in this month/year ? most number of questions answered in a month...maybe like a top 25 list...something on similiar lines?  I will add more once i think more on this.....but What do you guyz think ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should be looking at the

[**StackOverflow Data Explorer**](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries)

There are a lot of pre-made queries, and you can create your own. The dataset it runs against is the monthly cc-wiki datadumps provided by the StackExchange team.

Comment: Great that it exists but do we *really* need **another site**? This "trilogy" is going beyond even Douglas Adams' wildest dream... =:-)

Answer (score 2):

There is already a page that keeps track of the top answerers and questioners: [the stats page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?sort=stats&pagesize=50). You can even access stats for individual tags [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=c%23&sort=stats&pagesize=50), if you want.

Answer (score 2):

YES! I often see people answer questions with clever stats like average number of up votes per minute or whatever and I think, where did that come from?

Statistics can encourage users to e.g. write better questions / give better answers. And I guess SO wants to be open? So please publish and please **make them easy to find**!

Answer (score 1):

They have already stated that if they were to do this it would make the site feel more like a badge grab. IE I only need X more to get X. You can always use the stack exchange data explorer to get some idea where your at.